# how to make a data frame of pre-post score with two columns, group and score

Tags: r

I had two set of test scores:

```
pre  <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
post <- c(0,4,0,5,0,5,4,2)
```

I want to create a `data.frame` that has two columns, one is "group" that shows pre-test and post-test score (in order, pre score at the front), and one column that shows the score.

I've tried this code:

```
t<-data.frame(group = rep(c("pre", "post")),score = c(pre,  post))
```

It does not show the right order. it mixes up the pre/post test score. Could anyone help me with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
pre<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
post<-c(0,4,0,5,0,5,4,2)
t <- data.frame(group=c(rep('pre', length(pre)), rep('post', length(post))),score=c(pre,post))
t
```

Comment: Just adding that in the case where you don't know in advance how long the columns need to be you could use `group=c(rep('pre', length(pre)), rep('post', length(post)))`.